# Modern term for 'overwhelming information onslaught'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Grasping for a term that encapsulates the notion of struggling against and being overwhelmed by a torrent of information, which invokes 'The Paradox of Choice' or 'Choice Paralysis,' and falls under the format "a tragedy of errors;" "an embarrassment of riches:"

"a ________ of information."

Trying to avoid dealing exclusively with quantity, such as with 'plethora' or 'explosion,' and speaking more to the inability to fully take in what is being provided.

Comment: Something like a Babel, perhaps?

Comment: ***information overload***

Comment: _A googolplex of information_. 'Googleplex' is the HQ of Google, but a googolplex is 1 to the power of a googol, which is 1 followed by a hundred zeroes.

Comment: **Sensory overload** - a common malady at Christmastime.

Comment: I like Dan's suggestion (right on the money) but you could also try [drinking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drink_from_a_firehose) [from](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drinking%20from%20the%20firehose) [the](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drink+from+a+fire+hose) [fire](http://hubbub.typepad.com/blog/2006/10/office_talk_dri.html) [hose](https://www.oldtownhome.com/2014/1/13/Its-Sort-of-Like-Drinking-From-a-Firehose/). Something of a *cliché* now though.

Comment: Are you really trying to equate *information overload* with *choice paralysis*, please? Clearly, they overlap but equally clearly, they’re very different.

Comment: Let's not forget "TMI", but of course that term carries some connotations.

Comment: I would go for **overload**, too - but you could also try **deluge**, **storm**, **maelstrom**, **whirlwind**, **overabundance** or just **confusion**

Comment: @NigelJ: Actually, 1 to the power of a googol is 1. A googolplex is ***10*** to the power of a googol.

Comment: sensory overflow, virtual onslaught

Comment: Firehose is one common metaphor for this.

Comment: *Tsunami* of information...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word "inundation".

An inundation of information.

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/inundation):

> ## inundation
>
> /ˌinənˈdāSH(ə)n/
>
> noun
>
> An overwhelming abundance of people or things.
>
> *‘For some reason, it doesn't seems to suffer from the same inundation of spam that the other site does.’*

Answer (score 0):

A torrent of information. - connotations of overwhelming flood like a river.

Maybe, a surfeit of information. - connotation of too much information.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *overload*, call it an ***overflow*** of information:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overflow):
>
>   the number of people or things that goes over a limit
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overflow):
>
>   The overflow is the extra people or things
>     that something cannot contain or deal with because it is not large enough.
>   *Tents have been set up next to hospitals to handle the overflow.*
>   *The loch’s overflow cascades into the waterfalls of a Japanese water garden.*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/overflow):
>
>   (Computing) 
>     The generation of a number or some other data item
>     that is too large for an assigned location or memory space.

In your question, you speak of “the notion of struggling against
and being overwhelmed by a torrent of information, …” 
My favorite phrase relating to that is “too much analysis leads to paralysis”,
which I heard for the first time on an otherwise long-forgotten TV show. 
And, if you’re thinking “torrent”,
then a “flow”-related word seems especially appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has suggested **tsunami**:

> a great sea wave produced especially by submarine earth movement or
>   volcanic eruption : tidal wave

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsunami)

The term is often used figuratively with regard to information: http://www.creativeteachingsite.com/tsunami.htm

Answer (score 0):

**torrent**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/torrent)

> A heavy, uncontrolled flow